# Expect Script to Login and Run Local File on Sever

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I'm trying to use Expect to first login to the server then run a local file on the server.

I have an Expect script called `sshScript.exp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set username [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set sshHost [lindex $argv 2]

# ssh and run script in emr
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$sshHost "bash -s" < "./emrScript.sh"
expect "Enter your AD Password:" {
    send "$password\r"
    expect eof
}

# wait for exit code and return it
catch wait result
exit [lindex $result 3]
```

and `emrScript.sh` is located in the same directory as the Expect script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello EMR - this script is local"
echo "this script will pass"
exit 0
```

When I call `/usr/bin/expect sshScript.exp <username> <password> <host>`
It will display the prompt `Enter your AD Password:` then I get the error `bash: ./emrScript.sh: No such file or directory` because its trying to run the file from the server

But I can run just the command `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <username>@<host> bash -s < ./emrScript.sh` and it'll ask for my password and run the script accordingly from the local location.

What am I doing wrong in the expect script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spawn ssh $user@$host "bash -s" < "./emrScript.sh"` would actually run `ssh $user@$host "bash -s" "<" "./emrScript.sh"` which is the same as `ssh $user@$host "bash -s < ./emrScript.sh"`.

You can write like this:

```
spawn bash -c "ssh $user@$host bash -s < ./emrScript.sh"
```